# Multiple-entry Schengen visa with a work trip in-between

Tags: indian-citizens, multiple-entry, schengen-visas

I am an Indian citizen and will be travelling from India to the UK on work for 3 weeks (I have a business visa for the UK). During that time, I will be headed to France over a weekend. After the completion of my work, I will be headed to France (1 day), Germany (2 days), Slovenia (4 days), Italy (3 days) and Croatia (7 days).

Should I apply for my Schengen visa from France (given that I will be covering it twice)? Also, assuming that all bookings are done, is there likely a challenge for the multiple-entry visa?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, even dual entry should be sufficient (though multi is of course the safest option). Since France is your first visit's only destination it is quite natural to apply at French visa center.